# COBOL-COMPILATION ERROR In If statement :A scope-delimiter did not have a matching verb and was discarded

Tags: if-statement

Error in if statement all statements are ended properly

Comment: Count your `IF` statements again.  Then count your `END-IF` statements.  I suggest you format your code more conventionally, it helps to find these sorts of errors.

Comment: have a look at GIVING  AR04-STATUS. The `.` ends the previous if

Answer (score 4):

One obvious error is the line

```
        GIVING  AR04-STATUS.
```

The `.` ends the previous if.

#### Cobol Style suggestions

1. Code one `.` per paragraph/ section and put the `.` on a line by itself just prior to `I-EXIT`. On the mainframe you can do x all; x p'@$' all (I think its been a long time) that will find `.` at the end of the line.

   ```
          END-IF
       END-IF
       .

    I-EXIT.
   ```
2. You do not need `then` - remove
3. Indent your code properly

   ```
   IF  NOT SUCCESS           IN AR04-STATUS
   AND NOT DL-KEY-NOTFOUND-S IN AR04-STATUS
       SET CTB-MSG-ROUTINE-ERROR     TO TRUE

       MOVE "I-MTS-ACCOUNT-CHK"      TO CTB-SECTION-NAME

       MOVE "DCS_GT_SUBS_COUNT"      TO CTB-ROUTINE-NAME

       MOVE AR04-STATUS              TO CTB-ROUTINE-STATUS

       PERFORM X-HANDLE-ERROR

       PERFORM Z-FINISH
   END-IF
   ```

Makes it easier to read

Comment: I prefer to have the ending line “continue.” rather than just a period. I think it is clearer.